# Cannot find module '@apollo/client/core' or its corresponding type declarations.ts when trying to use graphql in angular setup

Tags: angular, ubuntu, npm, graphql, apollo-client

Hello I tried to use graphql with angular. I relatively new to both angular and graphql. I was trying to setup the schema for the graphql queries. for that I'm trying to install apollo-client since i'm getting an error in `graphql.module.ts` file that I created. The code for this is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
// Apollo
import { ApolloModule, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';
^
**Cannot find module '@apollo/client/core' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)**

import { ApolloClientOptions, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular/http';

const uri = ''

function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({ uri }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}

@NgModule({
  exports: [ApolloModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink],
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

So I tried to add apollo-angular using `ng add apollo-angular`. but I got this dependency error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: assessment@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@15.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"^14.0.0" from apollo-angular@4.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/apollo-angular
npm ERR!   apollo-angular@"4.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/fahim/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/fahim/.npm/_logs/2022-11-25T00_41_44_581Z-debug-0.log
```

In the `/home/fahim/.npm/_logs/2022-11-25T00_41_44_581Z-debug-0.log` I got:

```
0 verbose cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
1 info using npm@8.19.2
2 info using node@v18.12.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/home/fahim/coding_projects/gmh/angular_fronted/github_angular_frontend/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
11 timing config:load:file:/home/fahim/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 7ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 7ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 3ms
21 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
22 verbose title npm install apollo-angular@4.1.1
23 verbose argv "install" "apollo-angular@4.1.1"
24 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
26 timing npm:load:display Completed in 3ms
27 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/fahim/.npm/_logs
28 verbose logfile /home/fahim/.npm/_logs/2022-11-25T00_41_44_581Z-debug-0.log
29 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 3ms
30 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
31 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
32 timing npm:load Completed in 18ms
33 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
34 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
35 silly logfile done cleaning log files
36 verbose shrinkwrap failed to load node_modules/.package-lock.json out of date, updated: node_modules
37 timing idealTree:init Completed in 293ms
38 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2ms
39 silly idealTree buildDeps
40 silly fetch manifest apollo-angular@4.1.1
41 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/apollo-angular 933ms (cache miss)
42 silly fetch manifest @angular/core@^15.0.0
43 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore 396ms (cache updated)
44 silly fetch manifest @angular/core@^14.0.0
45 silly fetch manifest rxjs@~7.5.0
46 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs 89ms (cache revalidated)
47 silly fetch manifest zone.js@~0.12.0
48 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js 90ms (cache revalidated)
49 timing idealTree Completed in 1822ms
50 timing command:install Completed in 1827ms
51 verbose stack Error: unable to resolve dependency tree
51 verbose stack     at [failPeerConflict] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1381:25)
51 verbose stack     at [loadPeerSet] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1347:34)
51 verbose stack     at async [buildDepStep] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:930:11)
51 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:211:7)
51 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
51 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:153:5)
51 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:145:5)
51 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:78:5)
52 verbose cwd /home/fahim/coding_projects/gmh/angular_fronted/github_angular_frontend
53 verbose Linux 5.15.0-52-generic
54 verbose node v18.12.1
55 verbose npm  v8.19.2
56 error code ERESOLVE
57 error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
58 error
```

Can anyone help me resolve the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use  `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps`

```
npm install apollo-angular --force
```